# post request of the crud functionality not working in my django rest_framework app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a crud API using Django rest_framework the get request seems to work fine
for me but the post request is not working at all when I try to print the request.data it gives an empty dictionary

Please help me to resolve this issue

views.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import freelancerJob
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .serializers import jobPostSerializer
from django.views import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK,HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import parser_classes
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import viewsets



@csrf_exempt

@api_view(['GET', 'POST','DELETE'])
@parser_classes([JSONParser])
def jobPostView(request,format=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("data",request.data)
        serializer = jobPostSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer.initial_data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse({'data':serializer.data},status = HTTP_200_OK )

        else:
            return Response({'status':'error','data':serializer.data},status = HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    if request.method == "GET":
        data = freelancerJob.objects.all().order_by('id')
        serializer = jobPostSerializer(data ,many = True)
        return Response({"status":'success','data':serializer.data},status = HTTP_200_OK)
```

My serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import freelancerJob

class jobPostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def create(self,validated_data):
        return freelancerJob.object.create(**validated_data)


    class Meta:
        model = freelancerJob
        fields = ['title','description','skill','duration','budget','types']
```

my models.py file

```
from operator import truediv
from django.db import models

class freelancerJob(models.Model):
    Job_duration = (
        ('1','Less than 1 month'),
        ('3','1 to 3 months'),
        ('6','3 to 6 month'),
        ('12','More than 6 months')
    )
    Job_type=(("Individual",'Individual freelancer'),
                ('Team','Team')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=False)
    skill= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=50 ,blank=False,choices=Job_duration)
    budget = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    types = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,choices=Job_type)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I try to print the request.data that is coming from the post request it gives an empty dictionary

[image: when trying to send post request from postman]

Comment: Looks like you send data with query params. You can check this by printing `request.query_params`. If you want your data be available from `request.data` you should provide it within request body. You can use Postman to send POST request with body.

Comment: thanks it worked , but I am still confused about why request.data did not worked because  I think it include all types of request and not only request.get

Comment: No, it's only for POST, PUT and PATCH. You can find details here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data

Comment: yeah was referring to that only , but I was trying for a post request which can be handled by request.data but this isnt happening why?

Comment: I think this is because you pass them as query params. Maybe this tutorial about sending POST request will be helpful: https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/